# Nightwatcher selenium. How to press: CTRL + SHIFT + j

Tags: selenium, nightwatch

I have tried every combination I came up with with no success.

```
browser.keys( [ browser.Keys.CONTROL, browser.Keys.SHIFT, 'j' ] )

browser.keys( browser.Keys.CONTROL + browser.Keys.SHIFT + 'j'  )

browser.setValue('.some_elem',  [ browser.Keys.CONTROL, browser.Keys.SHIFT, 'j' ] )

browser.keys( [ browser.Keys.CONTROL, browser.Keys.SHIFT, 'j', browser.Keys.NULL ] )

browser.keys( [ browser.Keys.CONTROL, browser.Keys.SHIFT, 'j' ] )
browser.keys( browser.Keys.NULL )


browser.keys( browser.Keys.CONTROL )
browser.keys( browser.Keys.SHIFT )
browser.keys( 'j' )
browser.keys( browser.Keys.NULL )
```

etc.

Any idea how to make it work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The official document introduces keyboard operation and how to press a modifier key (CONTROL, SHIFT, ALT). [Selenium doc > Keyboard](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/keyboard/)

Demo in Java:

```java
Actions actionProvider = new Actions(driver);

// Press CTRL + SHIFT + j
Action keydown = actionProvider.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("j").build();

keydown.perform();
```

You can find all keys here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html

---

**Another way:**

I have seen this way, but I haven't used it myself.

```java
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SHIFT, "j"));
```

Comment: Hi. I am using Nightwatch with javascript and I haven't seen these methods or classes (keyDown, Actions, etc) on the documentation or any sample code on internet.

Comment: @educob Sorry, I have no experience in Nightwatch with javascript. However, there are demos of PURE JavaScript in the official documentation of Selenium, as follows: `await driver.actions().keyDown(Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('a').perform();`. So see the url `Selenium doc > Keyboard` in my answer, and switch the language tab.

Comment: Hi, @educob, if this is the solution to your problem, please [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or [Vote up it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: I already up voted your answer. I didn't know one had to accept an answer but my problem remains. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for adding a comment to a wrong question, I will delete it. Good luck, hope your problem can be resolved soon.